# Power BI - How do you calculate first Day of Week?

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

So here is my scenario.
If it's 20th week of the Year 2016, I need to know it's 5/8/2016. This is consistent for the rest of week. Same goes for all the week.

```
Week#   WeekDate
29     7/10/2016 0:00
30     7/17/2016 0:00
28     7/3/2016 0:00
31     7/24/2016 0:00
32     7/31/2016 0:00
33     8/7/2016 0:00
34     8/14/2016 0:00
```

Comment: Do you have a calendar/date table in your model?

Comment: Just updated the ticket with calendar/date table model

Comment: I would also recommend a calendar table, where you can add calculated columns. The Time Functions can be pretty helpful here, such as Weekday: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634550.aspx And Weeknum: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634572.aspx in order to solve your problem

Comment: Yes, you are right Nebi. Thanks for you help on this.

Answer (score 1):

```
dateadd(DAY,-(datepart(weekday,DATEADD(WEEK,30-1,CAST('2016'||'-1-1' AS DATE)))-1),DATEADD(WEEK,30-1,CAST('2016'||'-1-1' AS DATE)))
```

This works with Intersystems. You will have to construct your own date with the known year value and replace '30' with the known week value from your table

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the contribution, I did something like below and it worked. This is keeping Sunday as the first day of week.

If you want to use Monday or Tuesday, add +2, +3 in the WeekNum calculation below.

```
DATE(SampleTableWithDate.Year],1,1) - WEEKDAY(DATE(SampleTableWithDate.Year,1,1),1)  + (WEEKNUM(SampleTableWithDate.Date)-1)*7 + 1

Find the First Date of this Year    -  First Day of Week This Year                   + Add Weeks till Date
```